# undo-tree changed Treemacs layout when move history cursor in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, undo-tree-mode, treemacs

When I use Spacemacs with the Treemacs feature inside it, like the picture, I opened it by Alt Shift m + p + t
[image]

Then use Ctrl x + u to open undo-tree
[image]

When I move the cursor on the undo-tree by Ctrl + p, the layout had been resized
[image]

Even I close the undo-tree window, the layout didn't back to the first picture.
[image]

Why it happened? How to avoid it?

Comment: I am familiar with `undo-tree` and am unaware of any code that resizes windows.  It only uses `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, `switch-to-buffer` and `display-buffer`.  The culprit may possibly lie elsewhere.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you. I just installed Spacemacs v.0.300.0 . I didn't set any addon configuration after install it. This issue happened on both Linux and macOS.

Comment: I am not familiar with `treemacs`, but did a quick git clone and grep for `shrink` and `enlarge` and came up with the function `treemacs--set-width`.  In your debugging quest, consider copying `treemacs--set-width` to a `*scratch*` buffer and modify it by making it do nothing. e.g., comment out everything and then evaluate the modified function; e.g., the new function that could be evaluated looks like `(defun treemacs--set-width (width) "Doc-string." nil)`  You could even just type `M-x eval-expression RET (defun treemacs--set-width (width) "Doc-string." nil) RET`; and, then repeat your test.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for your advice. Maybe there are something config conflict by default.

Comment: If something is resizing windows, then the functions that have `shrink` and `enlarge` in their names are most likely responsible (with a few unlikely exceptions, e.g., where an `alist` to a `display-buffer` family of functions is expressly set with a particular width).  Once you track down the function responsible, then you can work your way backwards to where the function is called, and then devise a plan to deal with the situation.  You could even just put in some messages in the function mentioned in my previous comment to see when it gets called ...

Comment: In my own setup, I modified `undo-tree-visualize-undo` and `undo-tree-visualize-redo` to use `with-current-buffer` instead of `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, and that bypasses the problem with resizing window functions bound to the `window-configuration-change-hook` such as what is probably happening in your situation.  Here is a gist from a couple of years ago -- It would be necessary to compare the code to the current version of `undo-tree.el` to ensure everything else is still the same.  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/4765516cf58a1ccc1d11de63bacaff34

Comment: Putting a dot here, facing the same issue in spacemacs

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the function `undo-tree-visualizer-update-diff`, which contains a `(balance-windows)` command at the end. So the simple dirty trick is to re-define the function with that command commented out after loading `undo-tree`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'undo-tree

  ;; [2023-10-20 Fri] modify this function from undo-tree.el to prevent
  ;; re-balancing windows ------------------------------------------------------
  (defun undo-tree-visualizer-update-diff (&optional node)
    ;; update visualizer diff display to show diff between current state and
    ;; NODE (or previous state, if NODE is null)
    (with-current-buffer undo-tree-visualizer-parent-buffer
      (undo-tree-diff node))
    (let ((win (get-buffer-window undo-tree-diff-buffer-name)))
      (when win
        ;; (balance-windows); comment this line out 
        (shrink-window-if-larger-than-buffer win))))
  )
)
```